# Rails - MySQL First letter of table name on uppercase

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, uppercase

I'm new to Rails, and i'm connecting to a remote database. The connection is OK, but I'm getting the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'catalogo.productos' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `productos`
```

I know that the table that I'm trying to access is Productos and no productos. I've tried to use:

```
class Productos < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "catalogo"
  set_table_name "Productos"
end
```

But I keep getting the error. What I need to do? I can't modify the name of the table, I only have SELECT permissions.

I'll show the controller where the error shows

```
require "Producto.rb"

class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Products = Producto.find(:all)
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your model name should be singular. Change `class Productos` to `class Producto`

```
class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection "catalogo"
 set_table_name "Productos"
end
```

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, I'm still getting the same error.